# Approval Workflow OOTB SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, approval-process

I am still learning how workflows work and this is the first time I have used OOTB so needless to say, I coded much more than I needed to. With that being said, today we tested the approval which goes through each process (3 steps) for an approval and the approvers each receive an email (good). Now we want to reject and on the first rejection an email is to go to the Initiator to indicate the email was rejected and the reasons why and requested to resubmit if need be. We don't want (3 steps) to reject the new item, but if ONE of the three reject then the task sends an email and ends. At the moment it is going through all 3 steps. Help! And I am using SharePoint 2010.

Thank You,

SharePoint WF Newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This began as out of the box (OOTB) but ended up having cusomization added. 
To allow the program to reject as the first request for rejection, go into the 'Set Approval' and then 'Change the behavior of a single task'. From there scroll to 'When a task completes' then make sure that on rejection you have the workflow stop. Make sure to do this on ALL of the 'Set Approvals' you use in your workflow, otherwise the process will run to the very end requesting a reject from all users.